# net_io_connectionclosed error trying to send via office365 in c#

Tags: c#, .net, office365, smtpclient

I have looked at the other threads and have so far found no solution.
I get the net_io_connectionclosed error whenever I try to connect via the method below.

I am trying to use an Office 365 smtp relay. I do not have access to the main account or ability to change anything about this email so I cannot check settings or even reset the password.

Any and all help gratefully received.

**uname**: email address of the relay account (no-reply@[x].com)

*I am waiting on a reply to my email to get the onmicrosoft.com address, but it is not mentioned in any of the tutorials at all. As such the uname here is also in the msg as the 'from' address.*

**pwd**: password.

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.office365.com", 587);
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
client.EnableSsl = true;
client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(uname, pwd);
client.TargetName = "STARTTLS/smtp.office365.com";
client.Timeout = 10000;
client.Send(msg);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it turns out that using a relay for this is not possible unless you **own** the IPs (not supplied by Azure, netregistry etc.)

You have to buy a new mailbox from O365 and use that. Thus defeating the purpose of having a realy unless you run your own server (in which case I wouldn't need a relay as I would use my own smtp services.)

This means if you are running Azure, probably best to avoid O365 for email, other suppliers are far more flexible.

Link to the forum at MS: 
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_o365admin-mso_other/how-to-setup-an-smtp-relay-for-use-from-an-azure/5d997c38-bd67-4dbd-ad0d-62488addf9ae